How to pass the current index of component nested in another component?
I have a hero Component that has a background image and a carousel inside of it. I want to change the background images as I slide prev and next in my carousel depending on what is currently shown in the carousel. The CarouselPrev and CarouselNext are exported from the carousel component. They have onClick functions applied to them there so I can't apply an onClick function to those components in my hero component or they will override each other.
Carousel:

import * as React from "react";
import useEmblaCarousel, {
  type UseEmblaCarouselType,
} from "embla-carousel-react";
import { ArrowLeft, ArrowRight } from "lucide-react";

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { Button } from "@/Components/ui/Button";

type CarouselApi = UseEmblaCarouselType[1];
type UseCarouselParameters = Parameters<typeof useEmblaCarousel>;
type CarouselOptions = UseCarouselParameters[0];
type CarouselPlugin = UseCarouselParameters[1];

type CarouselProps = {
  opts?: CarouselOptions;
  plugins?: CarouselPlugin;
  orientation?: "horizontal" | "vertical";
  setApi?: (api: CarouselApi) => void;
  currentIndex: number;
};

type CarouselContextProps = {
  carouselRef: ReturnType<typeof useEmblaCarousel>[0];
  api: ReturnType<typeof useEmblaCarousel>[1];
  scrollPrev: () => void;
  scrollNext: () => void;
  canScrollPrev: boolean;
  canScrollNext: boolean;
  currentIndex: number;
} & CarouselProps;

const CarouselContext = React.createContext<CarouselContextProps | null>(null);

function useCarousel() {
  const context = React.useContext(CarouselContext);

  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useCarousel must be used within a <Carousel />");
  }

  return context;
}

const Carousel = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLDivElement,
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & CarouselProps
>(
  (
    {
      orientation = "horizontal",
      opts,
      setApi,
      plugins,
      className,
      children,
      ...props
    },
    ref
  ) => {
    const [carouselRef, api] = useEmblaCarousel(
      {
        ...opts,
        axis: orientation === "horizontal" ? "x" : "y",
      },
      plugins
    );
    const [canScrollPrev, setCanScrollPrev] = React.useState(false);
    const [canScrollNext, setCanScrollNext] = React.useState(false);
    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = React.useState(0);

    const onSelect = React.useCallback((api: CarouselApi) => {
      if (!api) {
        return;
      }

      setCanScrollPrev(api.canScrollPrev());
      setCanScrollNext(api.canScrollNext());
      setCurrentIndex(api.selectedScrollSnap());
    }, []);

    const scrollPrev = React.useCallback(() => {
      api?.scrollPrev();
    }, [api]);

    const scrollNext = React.useCallback(() => {
      api?.scrollNext();
    }, [api]);

    const handleKeyDown = React.useCallback(
      (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
          event.preventDefault();
          scrollPrev();
        } else if (event.key === "ArrowRight") {
          event.preventDefault();
          scrollNext();
        }
      },
      [scrollPrev, scrollNext]
    );

    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (!api || !setApi) {
        return;
      }

      setApi(api);
    }, [api, setApi]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (!api) {
        return;
      }

      onSelect(api);
      api.on("reInit", onSelect);
      api.on("select", onSelect);

      return () => {
        api?.off("select", onSelect);
      };
    }, [api, onSelect]);

    return (
      <CarouselContext.Provider
        value={{
          carouselRef,
          api: api,
          opts,
          orientation:
            orientation || (opts?.axis === "y" ? "vertical" : "horizontal"),
          scrollPrev,
          scrollNext,
          canScrollPrev,
          canScrollNext,
          currentIndex
        }}
      >
        <div
          ref={ref}
          onKeyDownCapture={handleKeyDown}
          className={cn("relative", className)}
          role="region"
          aria-roledescription="carousel"
          {...props}
        >
          {children}
        </div>
      </CarouselContext.Provider>
    );
  }
);
Carousel.displayName = "Carousel";

const CarouselContent = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLDivElement,
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => {
  const { carouselRef, orientation } = useCarousel();

  return (
    <div ref={carouselRef} className="overflow-hidden w-1/2 -ml-36">
      <div
        ref={ref}
        className={cn(
          "flex flex-row-reverse",
          orientation === "horizontal" ? "-ml-4" : "-mt-4 flex-col",
          className
        )}
        {...props}
      />
    </div>
  );
});
CarouselContent.displayName = "CarouselContent";

const CarouselItem = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLDivElement,
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => {
  const { orientation } = useCarousel();

  return (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      role="group"
      aria-roledescription="slide"
      className={cn(
        "min-w-0 shrink-0 grow-0 basis-full",
        orientation === "horizontal" ? "pl-8" : "pt-4",
        className
      )}
      {...props}
    />
  );
});
CarouselItem.displayName = "CarouselItem";

const CarouselPrevious = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLButtonElement,
  React.ComponentProps<typeof Button>
>(({ className, variant = "outline", size = "icon", ...props }, ref) => {
  const { orientation, scrollPrev, canScrollPrev } = useCarousel();

  return (
    <Button
      ref={ref}
      variant={variant}
      size={size}
      className={cn(
        "absolute h-8 w-8 rounded-full",
        orientation === "horizontal"
          ? "bottom-1/4 right-12"
          : "-top-12 left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 rotate-90",
        className
      )}
      disabled={!canScrollPrev}
      onClick={scrollPrev}
      {...props}
    >
      <ArrowLeft className="h-4 w-4" />
      <span className="sr-only">Previous slide</span>
    </Button>
  );
});
CarouselPrevious.displayName = "CarouselPrevious";

const CarouselNext = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLButtonElement,
  React.ComponentProps<typeof Button>
>(({ className, variant = "outline", size = "icon", ...props }, ref) => {
  const { orientation, scrollNext, canScrollNext } = useCarousel();

  return (
    <Button
      ref={ref}
      variant={variant}
      size={size}
      className={cn(
        "absolute h-8 w-8 rounded-full",
        orientation === "horizontal"
          ? "bottom-1/4 right-0"
          : "-bottom-12 left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 rotate-90",
        className
      )}
      disabled={!canScrollNext}
      onClick={scrollNext}
      {...props}
    >
      <ArrowRight className="h-4 w-4" />
      <span className="sr-only">Next slide</span>
    </Button>
  );
});
CarouselNext.displayName = "CarouselNext";

export {
  type CarouselApi,
  Carousel,
  CarouselContent,
  CarouselItem,
  CarouselPrevious,
  CarouselNext,
};

Hero:

import { getTop10 } from "@/lib/utils";
import {
  Carousel,
  CarouselContent,
  CarouselItem,
  CarouselNext,
  CarouselPrevious,
} from "@/Components/ui/carousel";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Card, CardContent } from "@/Components/ui/card";

const Hero = () => {
  const [top10, setTop10] = useState<any[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTop10 = async () => {
      try {
        const movies = await getTop10();

        if(Array.isArray(movies?.results)){
          setTop10(movies.results.slice(0, 10));
        } else {
          console.error('Data is not an array:', movies);
        }
      }
      catch(error) {
        console.error('Error fetching top10:', error);
      }
    };
    fetchTop10();

  }, []);

  
  const [currentMovieIndex, setCurrentMovieIndex] = useState(0);

  function handlePreviousClick() {
    setCurrentMovieIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex === 0 ? top10.length-1 : prevIndex - 1));
  }
  
  function handleNextClick() {
    setCurrentMovieIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex === top10.length-1 ? 0 : prevIndex + 1));
  }

  return (
    <div
      style={{ backgroundImage: `url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${top10[currentMovieIndex]?.backdrop_path})`, backgroundPosition: "center" }}
      className="w-full h-[1000px] bg-cover bg-center"
    > 
      <div className="container mx-auto pt-60 text-6xl text-white font-bold flex flex-col gap-6">
        <h1>{top10[currentMovieIndex]?.original_title}</h1>
        <div className="flex flex-row gap-4 items-center">
          <span className="px-4 py-1 bg-amber-700 text-black text-xl rounded h-fit">
            IMDB
          </span>
          <span className="text-3xl font-medium">{top10[currentMovieIndex]?.vote_average} / 10</span>
        </div>
        <Carousel
          opts={{
            align: "end",
            direction: "rtl",
            loop: true,
            duration: 40,
          }}
          className="w-full mt-20"
          currentIndex={0}
        >
          <CarouselContent>
            {top10.map((movie: any, index: number) => (
              <CarouselItem key={index} className="basis-1/3">
                <div className="p-1">
                  <Card style={{ backgroundImage: `url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie?.poster_path})`, backgroundPosition: "center" }} className="bg-cover bg-center w-full">
                    <CardContent />
                  </Card>
                </div>
              </CarouselItem>
            ))}
          </CarouselContent>
          <CarouselPrevious />
          <CarouselNext />
        </Carousel>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Hero;

Embla Docs has a method called selectedScrollSnap that will track the index but I am lost on how to use it and pass the value to my carousel. Then I'm not sure if this is even the correct way to go about trying to achieve the functionality I am looking for.

Not sure what I was on when I wrote this. I just wrapped the CarouselNext and CarouselPrevious components that were inside Hero component in a div and placed the onClick on those divs. Then got rid of all the weirdness I was doing with ScrollSnap in the Carousel component.
<div onClick={handlePreviousClick}>
  <CarouselPrevious />
</div>
<div onClick={handleNextClick}>
  <CarouselNext />
</div>

